# Unable to create session for handle using JavaRTO API

Tags: solace

I've been following the tutorial for Solace JavaRTO [low latency]

https://dev.solace.com/samples/solace-samples-javarto/publish-subscribe/

However, it seems that when I get to the part where you create the session for handle I run into the following error.

```
com.solacesystems.solclientj.core.impl.util.SolLogger log
WARNING: solClientSession.c:3715              (00002888) Bad context pointer (0000000000000000) in solClient_session_create
Dec 17, 2018 4:04:52 PM com.solacesystems.solclientj.core.impl.util.SolLogger critical
SEVERE: a uncaught exception was encountered on Thread Thread[main,5,main]
com.solacesystems.solclientj.core.SolclientException: errorStr [solClientSession.c:3715              (00002888) Bad context pointer (0000000000000000) in solClient_session_create] subCode [2:PARAM_NULL_PTR] responseCode [0] returnCode [-1:FAIL]
    at com.solacesystems.solclientj.core.impl.util.ExceptionGuard.assertReturnCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.solacesystems.solclientj.core.impl.util.ExceptionGuard.assertReturnCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.solacesystems.solclientj.core.impl.ContextHandleImpl.createSessionForHandle(Unknown Source)
```

Without the actual source I am unable to debug further to try and locate the issue but it sounds like some parameter might be incorrect or null. However, I have been able to successfully connect, publish and subscribe to Solace using the same params with the normal Java API.

Does anyone know if there are any properties that are specific to the low latency JavaRTO API or anything else that might be causing this issue?

Comment: Been staring at the screen too long. I accidentally closed the context earlier in the code.

Tldr: The tutorial works, stare at the screen less

Answer (score 1):

Tutorial works fine, I overlooked an earlier statement that closed the context handler prematurely.